# jQuery use :not selector with on

Tags: jquery, click

Having a bit of trouble. Please take a look at the following code.

```
$(document).on("click", "*:not(.parent-container a)", function(e) {
    // Do stuff if we have not clicked a link inside .parent-container
});
```

.parent-container is appended to the DOM. Then we want to bind a "click" event everywhere but to the links inside of .parent-container, but I am finding that when I click the links inside of .parent-container that "Do stuff if we have not clicked a link inside .parent-container" is still executing.

Any advice as to how to correctly avoid binding to ".parent-container a"?

Comment: .off('click', '.parent-container a', ....

Comment: it is because of event propagation... try something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7jwbG/1/

Comment: sorry http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7jwbG/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the right practice is to have two bindings (in fact, as your real application already have more bindings, and probably ones for the a elements, you don't add bindings, you just add the `return false`) :

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    // Do stuff if we have not clicked a link inside .parent-container
}).on("click", ".parent-container a", function(e) {
    // you probably already have something to do 
    return false; // avoid propagation, the other event handler won't be called
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/oReXICe/1/)

Comment: Actually, he wants to bind to `document`.

Comment: I don't know if this is important for the OP, but it should probably be mentioned that this also prevents the default behavior of the `a` and it will only prevent event handlers to be called that are added to `document`, so something like this `$('body').on('a', ... )` will be still called.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.parent-container a')) {
        console.log(e.target)
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7jwbG/)

Comment: looks better than using two handlers

Comment: @A.Wolff Not in the real world where there's probably already a binding for the a element.

Comment: @dystroy i'm quite confident you are correct but I cannot see it

Comment: @A.Wolff I mean : if you put a `a` element in your page and it doesn't leave the page when clicked, it's probably not just a simple link so you bound an event handler to it.